# Rspec, Poltergeist, Capybara not working with audio files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Using rspec-rails-3.5.2, poltergeist-1.11.0, and capybara-2.10.1

I created an audio object:

```
Bart.pumpAudio = new Audio("assets/audio/bart/pump.mp3");
```

I have a button that plays a sound when pressed

```
<div id="pump-button" class="button">Pump</div>

$("#pump-button").click(function() {
    ...
    Bart.pumpAudio.play();
    ...
});
```

It works when I run on a browser, but I get errors when trying to perform tests through rspec:

Testing Code:

```
page.find("#pump-button").trigger('click')
```

Testing Error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Bart.pumpAudio.play()')
```

Any ideas on how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the top of my js file seemed to solve my issue

```
var Audio = function() {
    return {
        load: function() {},
        play: function() {}
    }
}
```

[Source](https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-244870.html?s=5c41aabec2b71023a193652e607c65b7)

Comment: Poltergeist uses PhantomJS as its "browser".  Since PhantomJS doesn't support audio/video you can't test audio/video playback - what you've done is provided do nothing stubs for Audio elements.  Rather than adding it to your apps JS you're better off putting it in a separate JS file used only for testing and using the Poltergeist :extensions option to load it - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization -  See also: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2014/01/21/mocking-html5-apis-using-phantomjs-extensions